# increment the month end date by a n months in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to increment the month end date by n months but having some issues. Please note the 2022-06-30 for an example. It should have been 2022-07-31 but it is 2022-07-29.

```
x['date1']= pd.to_datetime(x.date, infer_datetime_format=True)   +pd.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd(n=1)
x[['date','date1']].drop_duplicates()


    date    date1
    0   2021-11-30  2021-12-31
526399  2022-01-31  2022-02-28
1046177 2022-05-31  2022-06-30
1720828 2022-06-30  2022-07-29
2397903 2022-07-31  2022-08-31
3068076 2022-08-31  2022-09-30
```

Comment: 2022-07-31 is not a business month-end. Did you mean to use `MonthEnd` instead of `BusinessMonthEnd`?

Comment: interesting how do i get calendar month end

Comment: As mentioned in an edit to my comment, `MonthEnd`.